# AS крашится при попытке поиска по директории в Linux

Tags: android-studio

Понимаю, что сейчас задаю вопрос в духе "угадайте, что у меня за проблема", но может хотя бы подскажете направление, где копать. Может студия пишет лог такого.

Суть проблемы в следующем
В Android Studio есть поиск по проекту (Ctrl+Shift+F), который позволяет искать в проекте вхождение строки в файле. Там есть возможность выбрать разные скоупы. Когда я выбираю "folder", нахожу папку, файлы в который собираюсь проверить и нажимаю "ок" студия повисает намертво секунд на 10, а потом перезагружается.

Хочу найти и искоренить причину, только не могу понять, где искать.